# Why is asyncio queue await get() blocking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, python-asyncio, producer-consumer

Why is **await queue.get()** blocking?

```py
import asyncio

async def producer(queue, item):
    await queue.put(item)

async def consumer(queue):
    val = await queue.get()
    print("val = %d" % val)

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await consumer(queue)
    await producer(queue, 1)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

If I call the **producer()** before **consumer()**, it works fine
That is to say, the following works fine.

```py
async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await producer(queue, 1)
    await consumer(queue)
```

Why isn't **await queue.get()** yielding control back to the event loop so that the producer coroutine can run which will populate the queue so that queue.get() can return.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to start the consumer and the producer in parallel, e.g. defining `main` like this:

```
async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await asyncio.gather(consumer(queue), producer(queue, 1))
```

If for some reason you can't use `gather`, then you can do (the equivalent of) this:

```
async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))
    asyncio.create_task(producer(queue, 1))
    await asyncio.sleep(100)  # what your program actually does
```

> Why isn't `await queue.get()` yielding control back to the event loop so that the producer coroutine can run which will populate the queue so that `queue.get()` can return.

`await queue.get()` **is** yielding control back to the event loop. But *await* means *wait*, so when your `main` coroutine says `await consumer(queue)`, that means "resume me once `consumer(queue)` has completed." Since `consumer(queue)` is itself waiting for someone to produce something, you have a classic case of deadlock.

Reversing the order works only because your producer is one-shot, so it immediately returns to the caller. If your producer happened to await an external source (such as a socket), you would have a deadlock there as well. Starting them in parallel avoids the deadlock regardless of how `producer` and `consumer` are written.

Comment: The producer and consumer are in different parts of the project, so I can't use asyncio.gather(consumer, producer). Is there a way to notify the consumer when the queue is not empty anymore?

Comment: Also, I didn't get this part - "when your main coroutine says await consumer(queue), that means 'resume me once consumer(queue) has completed'." If that is true then what is the difference between **await consumer(queue)** and **consumer(queue)**. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @AkshayTakkar Then start the consumer as a background task, using `asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))`. That will also eliminate the deadlock.

Comment: @AkshayTakkar `await consumer(queue)` means "block the current coroutine (allowing other coroutines to run) until `consumer` returns". `asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))` means "schedule `consumer` to execute in the event loop, but don't wait for it". Evaluating just `consumer(queue)` without awaiting it or passing it to a function almost never makes sense. Please refer to an asyncio tutorial for details.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you call `await consumer(queue)`, which means the next line (`procuder`) will not be called until `consumer` returns, which it of course never does because nobody produced yet

check out the Example in the docs and see how they use it there: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#examples

another simple example:

```py
import asyncio
import random


async def produce(queue, n):
    for x in range(1, n + 1):
        # produce an item
        print('producing {}/{}'.format(x, n))
        # simulate i/o operation using sleep
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
        item = str(x)
        # put the item in the queue
        await queue.put(item)

    # indicate the producer is done
    await queue.put(None)


async def consume(queue):
    while True:
        # wait for an item from the producer
        item = await queue.get()
        if item is None:
            # the producer emits None to indicate that it is done
            break

        # process the item
        print('consuming item {}...'.format(item))
        # simulate i/o operation using sleep
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)
producer_coro = produce(queue, 10)
consumer_coro = consume(queue)
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(producer_coro, consumer_coro))
loop.close()
```

Comment: My producer_coro and consumer_coro are in different parts of my project. I'm using the queue as a way to communicate between the producer and the consumer. Hence, I can't do asyncio.gather(producer_coro, consumer_coro) since producer_coro and consumer_coro are in different parts of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.run_until_complete()` with `.gather()`

Here is your updated code:

```
import asyncio

async def producer(queue, item):
    await queue.put(item)

async def consumer(queue):
    val = await queue.get()
    print("val = %d" % val)

queue = asyncio.Queue()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.gather(consumer(queue), producer(queue, 1))
)
loop.close()
```

Out:

```
val = 1
```

---

Also you could use `.run_forever()` with `.create_task()`

So your code snippet will be:

```
import asyncio

async def producer(queue, item):
    await queue.put(item)

async def consumer(queue):
    val = await queue.get()
    print("val = %d" % val)

queue = asyncio.Queue()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(consumer(queue))
loop.create_task(producer(queue, 1))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.close()
```

Out:

```
val = 1
```